# does IE 10 preview version support CSS 3d transforms like rotateX

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I found that IE 9 does not have this support while chrome,safari do have it.
Can someone tell if the support for features like rotateX and translateZ has been included in IE 10 preview version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. At the moment they are a bit buggy and a little incomplete, but they will be working by the time it's released.

It's pretty easy to test yourself, you can run Win 8 consumer preview in a virtual machine if you want IE10 now, though the Windows 7 version will be out sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have a look at this page: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/02/02/css3-3d-transforms-in-ie10.aspx

First result of a simple Google query...

Comment: yes.i found that link.but I was not able to found out the "transition end" event for the page

Comment: Well. Simple answer to your question: "Yes, it does" =)